# What is the meaning of "uber-"?

Tags: meaning, phrases

What is the meaning of "uber-"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The German word *über* is a cognate of the Greek *ύπερ* and Latin *super*.

In the German language it exists as preposition, prefix, adverb and translates on its own. It has many translations, and indicates a state or action involving **increased elevation** or **quantity** in the physical sense, or **superiority** or **excess** in the abstract (dictionary). It is defined by context or compounds, such as, but not limited to *over, about, around, among, by, via, through*,

Some examples

```
übertragen - to transfer, to hand over
übernehmen - to take over
überkommen - to overcome
übertreiben - to exaggerate
überhaupt - at all
überall - anywhere
überfüllt - overcrowded
über 10 Sekunde - more than 10 seconds (misused as "in ten seconds...")
```

In English, usually *slang*, denotes a **superlative**, **excessive** or **extreme**, translating as such (e.g. super, more than any).
Words such as superman [derived](http://www.yourdictionary.com/superman) from the German word.

On a side note. Latin also knows *ubertas* and *uber*. The former translates as fertile growth, abundance, fruitfulness. In English we know it as *uberty*. *Ubertas* is derived from the Latin adjective *uber* (fertile) and originated as noun meaning breast, udder.

Comment: +1, also note the *ver* in [Vercingetorix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vercingetorix) seems to be a Celtic cognate (with rix cognate to rex, rikjs, ri).

Answer (score 6):

über in german means over or above.  Like there might be an overlord... someone above other lords.   The slang of the internet has made this become more like "super".  It generally means that whatever it is modifying is above others.

Comment: Actually, as stated in my answer, it can also mean actual elevation, rather than the abstract. I think you are referring to the better-known term Übermensch, a name Nietsche, F. (1885) used for the higher state to which he felt men might aspire.

Also by the internet, did you mean games - because everything I know and can find on the background in the English language seems to indicate computer games in particular (and television).

Comment: ubergeek is common, and not particularly games-related

Answer (score 2):

As reported by the NOAD *uber* is a word used to denote an outstanding or supreme example of a particular kind of person or thing, as in *uberbabe*, or *uberregulator*.

The word has origin from the German *über* (*super*).

Comment: It means over in geman, not super.

Comment: @UpTheCreek: ["Super" means "over" in English too.](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wiktionary/en/wiki/super-)

Comment: @Mr.ShinyAndNew there is no single meaning or the German über, the english super- is only a prefix, not a noun.

Comment: @Derk-Jan: I'm not sure what you mean. Kiamlaluno said that the English word "uber" comes from the German word "über", which he translated as "super". UpTheCreek was saying that it doesn't mean "super", it means "over", but "super" also means "over". Yes, it's used as a prefix. Is that a problem? Does that make kiamlaluno wrong?

Comment: @Mr.ShinyAndNew Super only means over as a prefix. über doesn't need to be a prefix. Therefore, the translation to solely super is wrong.

Comment: @Derk-Jan: I think you're over-stating this. über can be translated to super. That's not the only translation, but it is not wrong.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyAndNew I never said the translation is wrong, but stating it as common translation, as only translation, as exact translation is. Über has much broader use, as explained in my post than super has by any means. The explanation @kiamlaluno provided is fine with me, but such translation can throw people off.

Answer (score 0):

[uber](http://www.wordnik.com/words/uber) means

> –adjective
>
> Super; high-level; high-ranking

and

> –adverb
>
> Very; super

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I think you're all missing the point.

Yes, `uber` is just German for "over", but in 1883, Nietzsche coined the word *Übermensch* (usually translated as "superman", long before Clark Kent's alter-ego hit the newsstands) and then some other Germans, shall we say, overdid the idea, applying it not to the superior individual but to what they were pleased to call the *Herrenvolk*, the master race.  Since then, the *uber*- prefix has had rather a nasty edge, bringing the connotation of something that by holding itself superior to mankind, has lost its humanity.

Comment: Nietzsche actually applied it to the Aryan race. Also, do you have a reference to your notion that is has a nasty edge?